# WordPress Syntax highlighter for posts

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a syntax highliter for WordPress that works with page builders like VC, Thrive and Elementor.

plugins like Enlighter, Caryon work perfectly with WordPress editor, but when I use a page builder it doesn't deal with it as a block of code.

Any tips

Comment: Did you find anything? I try Elementor + Enlighter, but got some trouble, especially with highlighting HTML code.

Comment: No , but I do the following ,I made a wordpress blog where I use Caryon plugin then copy the the source code of the generated blog into html elementor block